# What's the interior of $R^{\infty}$ in the $R^{\omega}$ with the box topology and the production topology?

Tags: general-topology, box-topology

What's the interior of $R^{\infty}$ in the $R^{\omega}$ with the box topology and the production topology?
With $R^{\infty}$ being the set of all eventually zero sequences.
About the question in Prob. 5, Sec. 20 in the book Topology by James R. Munkres, 2nd edition.

Comment: Is the zero vector an interior point in either of these topologies?

Comment: To clarify, $R^{\omega}$ consists of all real valued sequences, yes?

Comment: $R^ω$  consists of all real valued sequences.

Comment: The interior is the empty set in both of them :)

Comment: @astrobarrel Could you show how to prove that?

Comment: (i) show it's enough to prove that $0$ is not in the interior (ii) show that any neighbourhood of $0$ in the box topology has a vector with infinitely many non-zero components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $(x_n)$ be a point from $\Bbb R^\infty$, taking $\Bbb R^\omega$ in the *box* topology.

Suppose that there is a basic box open set $U=\prod_n U_n$ such that $(x_n) \in U \subseteq \Bbb R^\infty$, with all $U_n$ open in $\Bbb R$ and of course $x_n \in U_n$. This means that for each $n$ there is an $r_n>0$ such that $(x_n -r, x_n+r) \subseteq U_n$.

As $(x_n)$ is eventually constant, there is an index $N$ such that $x_n=0$ for all $n \ge N$. Then the sequence $(y_n)_n$ with $y_n = x_n$ for $n < N$ and $y_n = \frac{r}{2}$ for $n \ge N$, is *not* eventually constant but *is* in $U$ by definition, contradicting $U \subseteq \Bbb R^\infty$ (now refuted by $(y_n)$).

So no point of $\Bbb R^\infty$ is interior point in the box topology so its interior is empty. And if $(x_n)_n$ would have been an interior point in the product topology, it would also have been one in the box topology (as this topology is larger) and so the interior in the product topology is also empty.

BTW, $\overline{\Bbb R^\infty} = \Bbb R^\omega$ in the product topology, while $\overline{\Bbb R^\infty} = \Bbb R^\infty$ in the box topology.

Comment: Clearly.
Thanks a lot!